# Returning home on an expired passport

Tags: schengen, passports, europe, us-citizens, eu-citizens

I am an EU/US dual national. I am returning from a trip to California back home to Brussels. However, in the meantime, my European passport has expired! I have no other forms of European ID with me.

Must I enter the EU on my US passport, as a tourist, or is there some other way?

Comment: I assume I cannot enter the EU on an expired EU passport, so must use my valid US one ... I was avoiding this because I think I will just get a 90 day tourist visa on the border

Comment: Great, if it's no problem to enter the EU on a expired EU passport, then it's really no issue! But otherwise, the problem is that  no one ever checks passports on the Belgian border, so I'd have a hard time getting an exit stamp on my US passport once to avoid violating my 3 month tourist visa (and maybe incurring a fine).

Comment: If I stay "overstay" my tourist visa, I assume there's a penalty!

Comment: They cannot fine you for staying in Schengen because you are Belgian.  You don't lose your rights as a Belgian just because you show a US passport at the border.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Timatic tells me](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=BE&AR=US&EM=US&DE=BE&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) that an expired passport is accepted, as long as it has been expired for less than five years. You can also use a national identity card, but it is not accepted if it is expired.

> Passport required.
>
> - Nationals of Belgium are allowed to enter with an expired passport. The passport is accepted when expired for a maximum of 5 years.
> - Nationals of Belgium traveling without a passport must have a document accepted for entry, valid on arrival.
>
> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of Belgium with a national ID card.
> - Nationals of Belgium with an emergency or a temporary passport.